# Make SQL query faster that it is

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have the below query that it works fine but it takes time.
And the table is being bigger and bigger so it takes more and more time.
Is there any way to make this query faster?
 The query is here:

```
SELECT        patient.bartar_id, patient.bartar_enteringthesystem, patient.bartar_proviencename, patient.bartar_cityname, patient.bartar_coloplastrepname, patient.bartar_consultorname, 
                     patient.bartar_provienceofsurgeryname, patient.bartar_cityofsurgeryname, patient.bartar_surgeryhospitalname, patient.bartar_doctorsname, patient.bartar_patientstatusname, patient.bartar_ostomytypename, 
                     patient.bartar_insurancetypename, patient.bartar_ostomytimename, patient.bartar_dateofseurgery, patient.bartar_deathhealeddate, patient.bartar_customercode, patient.bartar_name, patient.bartar_family, 
                     patient.bartar_age, patient.bartar_birthyear, patient.bartar_connectornursename, patient.bartar_hastakmiliname, patient.bartar_doctorsname AS Expr1, patient.bartar_patientstatusname AS Expr2, 
                     patient.bartar_generalstatusname, patient.new_description AS CCDesc, patient.bartar_visitname, patient.bartar_repvisitname, patient.bartar_salename, patient.bartar_customersstatusname, r.bartar_date, 
                     r.bartar_delay, r.bartar_nextcall, r.new_newcaller, r.bartar_bagPerMonth, r.bartar_brand, r.bartar_paste, r.bartar_bag, r.bartar_acc, r.bartar_insuranceinfo, r.bartar_pastePerMonth
FROM            Filteredbartar_newpaitient AS patient INNER JOIN
```

and the rest is here:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT bartar_patientname,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_date
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_date IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_date,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_delay
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_delay IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_delay,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_nextcall
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_nextcall IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_nextcall,
(SELECT        TOP (1) new_newcaller
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (new_newcaller IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS new_newcaller,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_brandname
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_brand IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_brand,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_pastename
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_paste IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_paste,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_bagname
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_bag IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_bag,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_accname
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_acc IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_acc,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_pastepermonth
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_pastepermonth IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_pastePerMonth,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_bagepermonth
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_bagepermonth IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_bagPerMonth,
(SELECT        TOP (1) bartar_insuranceinfoname
FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS c2
WHERE        (bartar_patientname = cte.bartar_patientname) AND (bartar_insuranceinfo IS NOT NULL)ORDER BY bartar_date DESC) AS bartar_insuranceinfo
                           FROM            Filteredbartar_callcenterreport AS cte) AS r ON r.bartar_patientname = patient.bartar_newpaitientid
                           --where patient.bartar_enteringthesystem > @Fromdate and patient.bartar_enteringthesystem < @Todate
ORDER BY patient.bartar_enteringthesystem ASC
```

Comment: the time is around 4:30  min

Comment: Looks like very bad query. With so many subselects, you definitely need new DB/query design.

Comment: I cant understand why you have so many subqueries when you could use joins to obtain the data using ID's instead. there woudld be no need for `TOP (1)` if you used the PK's to locate records.

Comment: Are those two parts together the whole query? Why showing us it in two parts?

Comment: What's your SQL Server version?

Comment: Thanks for your comments
Two parts are one query.
I had to use like this because  for join from table 1 to table 2, for each record on table 1 there are 0 to n numbers of records related to that in table 2.
And in the join I want to get the latest column of table 2 that is not null.
So I have to get each column seprated.

Comment: Again: What's your SQL Server version?

Comment: My SQL version is 2008

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of all the top 1 sub
just join or left join

```
min(bartar_date)... 
from   
group by bartar_patientname
```

Comment: Would you describe it more, I didn't get your answer.
Tnx